# use operator as constructor in prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm writing a function called `leagalCourse`, it takes just one parameter, a course list. A course like, for example, `john+mary+94` would represent a project done by John and Mary with a mark of 94.

- It should be `true` if the course data is “legal”, which means that it  must not have a project with the same name twice such as `john+john+70`.
- There also must not be two projects in the list containing the same pair of students. So if there’s a project `harry+ron+82` in the list, it would be illegal for the list also to contain `harry+ron+90` or `ron+harry+63`.

There is a sample output:

```
?- legalCourse([one+two+3,four+five+6,one+six+7]).
true.

?- legalCourse([one+two+3,four+four+6,one+six+7]).
false.

?- legalCourse([one+two+3,four+five+6,one+two+7]).
false.

?- legalCourse([one+two+3,two+one+6,one+six+7]).
false.
```

This is what I tried:

```
legalCourse([]).
legalCourse(X) :-
        diffName(X).
legalCourse([Project|M]):-
        diffName(Project),
        not(samePair([Project|M])),
        legalCourse(M).

diffName(Name1+Name2+_) :-
        Name1 \= Name2.

/*can not have duplicated group*/
samePair([Name1+Name2+_|More]) :-
        append([[head],tail,More]),
        member(Name1,[head]),
        member(Name2,[head]).
```

The function partially worked before I added the samePair predicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this works, you need to switch the vars and check both are different in check_no_dups/1.

```
legalCourse(List):-
 maplist(triple_double,List,ListDouble),
 check_no_dups(ListDouble).

check_no_dups([]).
check_no_dups([H|T]):-
   H =X+Y,
   maplist(dif(H),T),
   H2 =Y+X,
   maplist(dif(H2),T),
   check_no_dups(T).

triple_double(X+Y+_Z,X+Y):-dif(X,Y).
```

Comment: You dont need H and H2, but I put them in, as I think it makes it clearer.

Comment: thank you so much Sir! I'm wondering how could dif( ) work with only one var? I can only find  dif/2 ,dif/3 online, does  maplist(dif(H),T) mean every element in T can not equal  H?

Comment: maplist(dif(H),T). is using dif/2. Its fixing the first argument as H and saying that every element in T iis not equal to it as you say ie maplist(dif(1),[a,b,c]), does dif(1,a),dif(1,b),dif(1,c).  In contrast If I did maplist(dif,[1,2,3],[a,b,c]), then I would be comparing two lists pair wise. ie. dif(1,a), dif(2,b),dif(3,c).  Ps. Please mark the answer as accepted if it solves your question.